# Is regression method the best for my case?

Tags: ai-design, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

newbie here. I'm starting to work on a custom model for a very specific task, so I found no pre-trained models for this task so far.

After checking (un)supervised learning approaches I believe that regression will work the best, but could you please take a look and say if there's something better around?

The data is like that:

```
input1(int) input2(float) input3(int) => output(int)
```

The set of `[inp1, inp2, inp3]` is unique and can generate only one `output`. There are always two and only two such sets that generate the same output (like `[2, 5.0, 3] => 0` and `[12, -3.0, 1] =>0` too). It's always three inputs in a set (no less, no more), I see no reason to consider there's anything like a label, output varies from +100million to -100 million or even more in the future.

There will be no texts, the data is not time-correlated. The full dataset size is a few hundred million of such sets, if it matters.

So, is regression the best choice here? Any advice on this task for beginner?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the meaning of the output ? Is there some ordinal order ? Like is is better to predict $2$ or $58$ when you expect $3$  ? If it is classification both are usually as bad (like predicting horse or dog instead of pandas, both errors are as bad) while regression is sensible to numerics.

Comment: Classification models predict a label. In your case that may be a whole number (e.g. 0, 1, 2, ...). Regression models predict a value. An important question is: How many possible outputs do you expect to have? If it is limited and the values are whole numbers you could treat the problem as a classification problem.

Comment: @Lelouch, Brian, it is hardly classification because output varies from +100million to -100 million or even more in the future. And yes, getting 58 is much worse than 2 if we expect 3.

Comment: So its probably regression then. Try the simplest model and increase the complexity if needed.

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell What you said makes no sense, classification predicts discrete values, regression predicts continuous values, value and label have no interesting meaning in your comment.

Comment: Predicting integers is classification, not regression, as integers are discrete values.

Comment: @Dr Snoopy you confirmed what I said: Predicting integers is classification. I said that the labels can be the whole numbers, i.e. integers.

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell Labels can be continuous or discrete, being a label does not imply classification.